# How to copy one property value to all the test cases in bulk - zephyr scale

Tags: jira-zephyr

If we have one test case like Test cas1 having developer property value as dev1 I want to copy this value to another property in the same test cases..
This I wanted to do in bulk way because I have 1000 test cases.

Answer (score 0):

To use a property for multiple test cases in a bulk, the easiest way that comes to my head is by using common datasets.
You can see illustrated explanation to do so [here](https://support.smartbear.com/zephyr-scale-cloud/docs/test-cases/data-driven-test-design.html#:%7E:text=Applies%20to%20Zephyr%20Scale%20Cloud,reused%20across%20different%20test%20cases.)